# How to ser fastApi web app on web server?

Tags: python, web, server, fastapi

I have a problem with starting my web app coded in python fastApi. It runs trough uvicorn but whatever i put as --host param(I put Ip address of server hosting my web app) I get this err.

ERROR:    [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Ip address and port are ok. I also tried putting my domain as --host param but it doesnt work. Same error always.

Please help. I just need to deploy my fastApi aplication on web server.

Comment: Also this is the script that i am triying to run
uvicorn main:app --host 194.146.59.72 --port 80 --reload

Comment: You should surely have a firewall. Have you opened the port on that?

Comment: No man, but i have garanteed that port is valid. Its the only port available on hosting platform.

Comment: Use host `0.0.0.0` to broadcast

Comment: My app started, so its not the problem in port, its problem in ip address? @roganjosh